# Make nodes move to end point from different starting points at same speed

Tags: swift, animation, sprite-kit, skaction

I have a line of SKSPriteNodes, I want those nodes to move from top of the screen to the bottom, those nodes are not at the same CGPoint, they are behind each other forming a line, When I use the normal SKAction.MoveToY() and I give it duration they move at variant speed in order to all arrive at the same time, What I want is for all nodes to move at the same speed and arrive one after the other, keeping thier line form.

Here is how I create them:

```
     for i in 0...5 {
         let enemy = SKSPriteNode(imageNamed: "Enemy")
         enemy.position = CGPoint(x: size.width / 2, y: size.height + enemy.size.height * CGFloat(i))
         addChild(enemy)
         enemy.runAction(SKAction.moveToY(0 - size.height, duration: 5))
        }
```

Comment: Look at speed, time and a distance formulas (eg. time = distance/speed) You have to define the speed to calculate the time (duration parameter). Distance is already known. Or, as an alternative, if possible, put all nodes in one container node, and move just that one node.

Comment: Would you please, elaborate more on the distance/speed calculation? distance is the entire height of the scene+enemy.position.y, speed is something I choose like 5 or 60?

Comment: Exactly. Checkout my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Because action's duration parameter directly affects on how fast node is moving, you have to calculate that parameter properly, because in your case, every enemy node should travel different distance. As I said in the comments, formula to calculate *time* (duration parameter) is:

> Time = Distance / Speed

You could do it like this:

```
class GameScene: SKScene{

struct Constants {
    static let enemySpeed:CGFloat = 100
}

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {


    print("Scene height : \(size.height)")

    print("Enemy speed : \(Constants.enemySpeed)")


    for i in 1...6 {

        //Creating random colors just for easier debugging.
        let randomColor = UIColor(red   : CGFloat(arc4random()) / CGFloat(UInt32.max),
            green : CGFloat(arc4random()) / CGFloat(UInt32.max),
            blue  : CGFloat(arc4random()) / CGFloat(UInt32.max),
            alpha : 1.0)

        let enemy = SKSpriteNode(color: randomColor, size:CGSize(width: 30, height: 30))
        enemy.zPosition = 10

        // Time = Distance / Speed

        let distance:CGFloat = frame.size.height + CGFloat(i) * enemy.size.height
        print("Enemy \(i) will travel \(distance) points")

        let duration = NSTimeInterval(distance / Constants.enemySpeed)
        print("Enemy \(i) will stop moving after \(duration) seconds")

        let enemyX = CGRectGetMidX(frame)
        let enemyY = frame.size.height + enemy.size.height/2 +  CGFloat(i) * enemy.size.height

        enemy.position = CGPoint(x: enemyX, y: enemyY)

        print("Enemy \(i) start position is \(enemy.position)")

        addChild(enemy)

        let endPosition = -enemy.size.height/2

        let move = SKAction.moveToY(endPosition, duration: duration)

         print("Enemy \(i) end position is \(-enemy.size.height/2)")

        enemy.runAction(move)
    }
}
```

}

As per 0x141E's suggestion, I've corrected distance calculation. Here is the output:

```
Scene height : 667.0
Enemy speed : 100.0
Enemy 1 will travel 697.0 points
Enemy 1 will stop moving after 6.97 seconds
Enemy 1 start position is (187.5, 712.0)
Enemy 1 end position is -15.0
Enemy 2 will travel 727.0 points
Enemy 2 will stop moving after 7.27 seconds
Enemy 2 start position is (187.5, 742.0)
Enemy 2 end position is -15.0
Enemy 3 will travel 757.0 points
Enemy 3 will stop moving after 7.57 seconds
Enemy 3 start position is (187.5, 772.0)
Enemy 3 end position is -15.0
Enemy 4 will travel 787.0 points
Enemy 4 will stop moving after 7.87 seconds
Enemy 4 start position is (187.5, 802.0)
Enemy 4 end position is -15.0
Enemy 5 will travel 817.0 points
Enemy 5 will stop moving after 8.17 seconds
Enemy 5 start position is (187.5, 832.0)
Enemy 5 end position is -15.0
Enemy 6 will travel 847.0 points
Enemy 6 will stop moving after 8.47 seconds
Enemy 6 start position is (187.5, 862.0)
Enemy 6 end position is -15.0
```

Comment: This works, and doesn't work at the same time, What I want is to move them to (0-enemy.size.height) because I want them to move to the top again, when I do this the problem occure again.

Comment: "...I want them to move to the top again..." Well, you haven't mentioned that part in your original question ;) You just said, you want to move enemies from the top to the bottom. So, update your original question with additional info and I will try to answer it... Note that (0 - x) == -x , so there is no need to write 0-enemy.size.height.

Comment: What you provided is a workaround, but thanks anyway.

Comment: @0x141E Yeah, thanks. I wanted to point that this was untested, but thought that OP will figure out by himself how to fix anything if needed because the the essence is there :)

Comment: @Abdou023 What do you mean by "workaround". It does exactly what you have asked in your question. You can use the same logic to create an action which will move enemies back to the top. You can use what Jacek Lampart pointed as well (especially because moveBy can be reversed). From what you have posted, I can't say what is optimal for you. Try to explain things better, that's all I can say right now.

Answer (score 1):

Try using moveBy: instead of moveTo: - that way you can make all the sprites move by the same amount.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10843211)

Comment: Rephrased from question to suggestion.